# Process.Start() - run 32bit native exe from .NET application

Tags: .net, process, x86, native

I've got the following issue. I'm trying to run 3rd-party x86 .exe application (specifically vc_redistr.x86.exe from MS) from my .NET executable - here is the code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = vcredistrPath;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " /install /passive /norestart";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

But when process.Start() is called I'm getting error saying that its incompatible with 64 bit OS. Of course, when I'm running this exe from command line it works just fine.
The question: is there any way how I can do it from my .NET app?

Comment: Could you please add the exact error message you are getting and maybe the link to the .exe file?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it won't work. `Process` is just a wrapper around Windows API calls. BTW you don't need a space before `/install` when specifying arguments.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the reason: the exe file itself appeared to be corrupted.